# Count number of words in unique sentences on domain

Tags: html

I am looking for a free tool (website, software) to do the following:

- Find all of the pages on a given domain name - if absolutely necessary, I can provide a list myself.
- Count the total number of words on all pages combined.

  - Filter out any repeated sentences from the word count (e.g count the footer only once, then ignore it for all other cases).
- Option to ignore elements with certain IDs or classes.

I need to give an estimate to a translation service about the number of words they need to translate for my website, but it would be too much work to do by hand (>2000 pages).

Comment: This would be simple to do if you program Python, which is easy to learn :-) Just use [Scrapy](https://scrapy.org/). I am sorry, but I don't know of an off the shelf app to do so. If you don't find one, your choices seem to be 1) learn Python or 20 pay someone, on a site live Fiverr Good luck

Comment: @Mawg I should probably clarify: I've tried already to do this is JS *and* Python - they both ended badly, because of buffer/RAM overload (and once accidently DDoSing my server). I just used `request` library in Python though - I might try Scrapy (I've not heard of it before). Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: There are two very well known Python scrapers - Beautiful Soup and Scrapy. Scrapy generally;y gets the vote, but feel free to try both. If you add the Python tag, it will act like the Bat Singal to Steve Barnes, our resident Python guru :-)  If you have buffer/RAM overload, consider restructuring your code, possiblt even writing interim results to text files on disk and freeing the data structures in RAM. But, try Scrapy first. Good luck :-)